# rearranging column data in loop

Tags: python, pandas, linux, bash, dataframe

I have a `data.csv` file it contain concatenated data as given below.
`>` are the separator of the concatenated files.

```
>
1.094   1.128   1.439
3.064   3.227   3.371
>
5.131   5.463   5.584
3.65    3.947   4.135
>
1.895   1.954   2.492
5.307   5.589   5.839
```

I want to  rearrange  the column data side by side and finally wants to save to new text file as depicted below.For this demo example we can create three files.Moreover extra 0 and 5 should be appended as extra rows.

```
cat file1.txt
1.094  5.131  1.895 0 5
3.064  3.65   5.307 0 5

cat file2.txt
1.128  5.463  1.954 0 5
3.227  3.947  5.589 0 5

cat file3.txt
1.439  5.584  2.492 0 5
3.371  4.135  5.839 0 5
```

My trial code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t')
for columns in df:
    data=df.iloc[:,columns]
data.concat['data']
data.to_csv('file1.txt')
```

error: ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types

I am not getting the expected output.Hope experts may help me.
Thanks.

Comment: please review the expected output and update accordingly (eg, why does `5.584 / 4.135` show up in `File2.csv`?) also consider updating the question to show the (wrong) output generated by your code; also, please confirm the number of columns in the input files ... will it *always* be 3 columns? can some files have a different number of columns? also, what is the expected max number of `>` separated data sets in the input file (sample shows `3`)

Comment: its a good question. I think you can use bash. I donot think this kind of facilities exist in pandas dataframe. As the community is big u would have got the answer so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- each `>` delimited block has 2 data rows
- data rows can contain a variable number of columns (`3` in the provided sample input)
- all data rows have the same number of columns (`3` in the provided sample input)
- output file names are of the form `fileI.txt` where `I` ranges from `1` to the number of columns in an input data row (`3` in the provided sample data)
- OP's host has enough RAM to hold the entire input file in memory (via `awk` arrays)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/^>/   { next }
       { if (! colcnt) colcnt=NF                         # make note of number of columns; used to deep track of number of output files
         for (i=1;i<=colcnt;i++)
             row1[i]=row1[i] (row1[i] ? OFS : "") $i
         getline
         for (i=1;i<=colcnt;i++)
             row2[i]=row2[i] (row2[i] ? OFS : "") $i
       }
END    { for (i=1;i<=colcnt;i++) {
             print row1[i],0,5 > "file" i ".txt"
             print row2[i],0,5 > "file" i ".txt"
         }
       }
' data.csv
```

**NOTE:** OP's sample code implies tab (`\t`) delimited input but additional comments from OP seem to indicate data is (variable) space delimited; input/output delimiters can be changed if/when OP provides an updated requirement for input/output delimiters

This generates:

```
$ head file*.txt
==> file1.txt <==
1.094 5.131 1.895 0 5
3.064 3.65 5.307 0 5

==> file2.txt <==
1.128 5.463 1.954 0 5
3.227 3.947 5.589 0 5

==> file3.txt <==
1.439 5.584 2.492 0 5
3.371 4.135 5.839 0 5
```

Comment: @snu sounds like your input file is different from what you've posted in the question; please update the question to include the output from `head -5 data.csv | od -c`

Comment: your sample code implies an input delimiter of tab (`\t`); my code assumes tab as the delimiter; I'm guessing your file does not actually contain tabs but rather spaces, this in turn would cause the output you're getting; the `od -c` output will confirm the actual column delimiter; in the meantime I'll remove the assumption of tab delimited inuput (and output) and just work with spaces .... answer updated

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6).
Assumptions: Unix line endings, data.csv starts with line containing only ">" and ends with an empty line.

```
for column in 1 2 3; do jq -Rsr --argjson column $column '
    split(">\n")[1:]
    |map(  
        split("\n")[:-1]|map(split("\t"))  
    ) as $arr
    |[ 
         [ $arr[][0][$column-1]],[$arr[][1][$column-1] ] 
         |.+["0","5"] 
         |join("\t")  
    ]|join("\n") 
' data.csv > file$column.txt; done
```

Result:

```
$ head file*.txt
==> file1.txt <==
1.094   5.131   1.895   0       5
3.064   3.65    5.307   0       5

==> file2.txt <==
1.128   5.463   1.954   0       5
3.227   3.947   5.589   0       5

==> file3.txt <==
1.439   5.584   2.492   0       5
3.371   4.135   5.839   0       5
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in python, use `numpy`. The following code should work I think, regardless of how many columns there are in the original file (`3` in your example). It does assume blocks of `2` rows. *Code below updated to take into account that the original file was in fact not separated by `tabs`, as initially suggested*.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fname = "data.txt" # file is apparently only separated with spaces, and then
# (one assumes) only for those lines that include data (not the lines with ">")
# some minor adjustments:

df = pd.read_csv(fname, header=None)

# get rid of rows with ">" separator
df = df[~df[0].str.contains('>')]

# now split all remaining rows
df = df[0].str.split(expand=True)

# change dtype (first col will be dtype "object" due to ">" separator)
df = df.astype(float)

col_len = len(df.columns)

# add some data
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0]*(col_len)*2,[5]*(col_len)*2]).reshape(4,col_len))

# concat orig data + added data
df_col = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)

# convert to numpy array, and reshape 
arr = df_col.to_numpy().reshape(int(df_col.shape[0]/2),2,col_len).T

# split up again
tup = np.split(arr,col_len)

# loop through tuple and write away the files
for idx, elem in enumerate(tup):
    # numpy arr will be nested, so get elem[0]:
    np.savetxt(f'file{idx+1}.txt', X=elem[0], fmt='%1.3f', delimiter='\t')
```

Result of `print(elem[0])` in the last loop:

```
[[1.094 5.131 1.895 0.    5.   ]
 [3.064 3.65  5.307 0.    5.   ]]
[[1.128 5.463 1.954 0.    5.   ]
 [3.227 3.947 5.589 0.    5.   ]]
[[1.439 5.584 2.492 0.    5.   ]
 [3.371 4.135 5.839 0.    5.   ]]
```

Comment: How about `df = df[~df[0].str.contains('>')]` instead of `df.dropna(inplace=True)`? I was assuming all your rows with ">" separator would have no value in the subsequent tabs, which when loaded into df, should result in NA values. But maybe you have lines like `>\t>\t>`?

Comment: How is that possible. That would mean that `df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep="\t", header=None)` followed by `df = df[~df[0].str.contains('>')]` produces a df with only 1 column and 3 rows, to which df2 adds 4 in `pd.concat()`? What does `df` look like after `df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep="\t", header=None)`? (print: `df.head()` or `df.tail()`)

Comment: Ok. That makes it a bit more complicated, because that surely means that your csv file isn't separated by tabs, like your question suggested, but that the values are simply separated by spaces, as @markp-fuso already surmised. Let me check how to resolve that. Meanwhile, maybe you could check the original text file, and update the question with what you find is the way it does or does not separate input. E.g. is it ">" followed by some spaces, or not? And are the values separated by tabs (just not the lines with ">"?)

Comment: Yes. I was getting to an update. See the answer. Delete any previous code (and any variables that were populated by it). Just pick the one above, and try again. Only need to change the reference to `fname`, of course. Your comments about strange output for `elem[0]` were to be expected, if the code wasn't processing the data correctly, on account of the confusion with the `tab` separation.